# InvalidPolicyDocument - Invalid Policy: Invalid Simple-Condition: value must be a string

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs, react-dropzone

Hopefully this helps someone else out. I had the `Expires:` key value as an integer and not a string. `30` vs `"30"`.

Was unable to tag this as `react-dropzone-uploader`.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with key field in the parameters. Changed it to string and the problem gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).